# Is it correct to say "imperturbably take damage"?

Tags: grammaticality

I have the next sentence:

> Stay calm and imperturbably take damage or die if need be.

Is it right? Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: There are probably better choices, but it seems OK to me.

Comment: (Though you might want to considered using "stoically".)

Comment: *Imperturbable* in this context is redundant as you are already telling someone to stay calm.

Comment: Perhaps ***impassively**?* But on purely stylistic grounds I'd resequence and rephrase to something more like *Remain calm, and face injury - or even death - impassively.*

Comment: Thanks for your replies, guys. I appreciate that.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about the sentence, and it can be easily understood. It's a little strange, but that's just a matter of style and personal opinion.

Comment: 'Imperturbably' sounds like a tongue-twister.

Answer (score 1):

Original:  “imperturbably take damage”

Its sounds very odd to me.  "Unflinchingly" (without moving) would sound better.

"Imperturbably" to me implies mental calm, focus, concentration.  Taking damage to your body would perturb your mental state, I would think, unless you are a 12th Level Buddhist master, or your limbs are paralyzed and can't feel pain.